# Json2: why does "var JSON" in global scope not clobber the global JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, scope

At the top of json2.js (line 160 after the comments: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), is the following code:

```
var JSON;
if (!JSON) {
    JSON = {};
}
```

Typically, declaring var something will set "something" to undefined:

```
var something = {};

(function(){
    var something;

    console.log(something); // logs undefined
})();
```

Normally I would accomplish this goal by using:

```
var JSON = JSON || {};
```

So what's with the global JSON object that allows writing "var JSON" to not set it to undefined?

And why on earth would someone like Crockford promote a technique, that, in any other situation, would NOT operate like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does this with any variable. Declaring it in the same scope again won't reset the value of the variable. I imagine it's a result of variable hoisting (all declarations are moved to the top of the function).

```
var a = 2;
var a;
console.log(a) // 2
```

In this specific case

```
var JSON;
if (!JSON) {
   JSON = {};
}
```

and

```
var JSON = JSON || {};
```

are pretty much equivalent. It's just a matter of style preferences.

Now, if he had put it inside the self executing anonymous function, the local JSON would be set to undefined.

If you're asking *why* he's doing that, it's because he doesn't want to overwrite the native JSON object if it exists, but I think you knew that already.

Comment: think you mean console.log(a) in your 1st example as yes console.log(2) is 2!

Comment: @Alex K.: Yeah, that what I meant.. fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten that differing scopes was the trigger, and not a redeclaration of a var. I've gotten so used to doing all of my declarations up front!